# BeanDefinitionStoreException IOException while accessing the application context file

Tags: spring

writing a simple spring program to read the bean from the filepathxmlapplication context, but getting the below exception.

but i am sure in can access the xml bean definition file.

```
public void testConnection() {
        try{

            List <LnkConnectionResponse> connResponse = new ArrayList <LnkConnectionResponse> ();


            log.info ("before xml resource");

            ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("M:/My Documents/workspace-sts-3.7.0.RELEASE/LDODashBoard/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mvc-database.xml");

            log.info ("before get bean");
            LnkConnectionWrapper linkConnectionArray = (LnkConnectionWrapper)context.getBean("linkConnectionArray");
```

### xml bean file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd">



   <util:list  id="dbnameList"  list-class="java.util.ArrayList">
        <value>LDMDB</value>
        <value>GCMMDB</value>
        <value>CVDBCHECKOUT</value>
        <value>CVEMEADBCHECKOUT</value>
        <value>LDMDB</value>
        <value>OPUSDB</value>
        <value>CDRDB</value>
        <value>TLMDB</value>
    </util:list>

   <util:list  id="urlList"  list-class="java.util.ArrayList"> 
        <value>ldmUnprocessedLink</value>
        <value>gcmmLink2</value>
        <value>dbCheckout</value>
        <value>dbCheckoutEMEA</value>
        <value>dbCheckout</value>
        <value>dbCheckout</value>
        <value>dbCheckout</value>
        <value>dbCheckout</value>
    </util:list>

   <util:list id="QueryList"  list-class="java.util.ArrayList"> 
        <value>select count( * ) from futures.EXMAN_STAGING where REGION = 'LONDON' and process_time_stamp is null</value>
        <value>select count( * ) from futures.EXMAN_STAGING where REGION = 'LONDON' and process_time_stamp is null</value>
        <value>select name from v$database } select market from cv_welcome where rownum &#60; 2</value>
        <value>select market from cvision.cv_welcome where rownum &#60; 2</value>
        <value>select 'X' from dual</value>
        <value>select 'X' from dual } select GET_PREV_BIZ_DATE from dual </value>
        <value>select dummy from dual } Select PREV_BUSINESS_DATE  From gmirpt.SD_GMI_PROCDATE  Where REGION_IND = 'ATL'</value>
        <value>select 'X' from dual</value>
    </util:list>

  <bean id="DBQueryBean" class="com.connection.impl.DBQueryImpl">
     <property name="DBName">
        <ref  bean="dbnameList"/>
     </property>
     <property name="UrlName">
        <ref  bean="urlList"/>
     </property>
     <property name="QueryString">
        <ref  bean="QueryList"/>
     </property>     
  </bean>

  <bean id="LdmDatabaseBean" class="com.connection.impl.LDMConnectionImpl">
     <property name="dbQuery" ref="DBQueryBean"/>
  </bean>

 <bean id="tlmWebConnectlink" class="com.implementation.LnkConnectionCheck">
    <property name="urlIDDesc" value="TLMWebConnect" />
    <property name="urlIDGroup" value="tlmlink" />
    <property name="urlLink" value="https://tlmapp.csintra.net/WebConnect/login/login.jsp" />
    <property name="urlDescription" value="TLM Web Connnect" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="linkConnectionArray" class="com.implementation.LnkConnectionWrapper">
    <property name="lnkConnectionCheck">
        <list>
           <ref bean="tlmWebConnectlink" />
        </list>
     </property>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

### Exception logs

> INFO  TestLnkConnection - before xml resource INFO 
>   FileSystemXmlApplicationContext - Refreshing
>   org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@61d83ac7:
>   startup date [Thu Dec 17 06:48:07 GMT+08:00 2015]; root of context
>   hierarchy INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions
>   from file [M:\My
>   Documents\workspace-sts-3.7.0.RELEASE\LDODashBoard\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\mvc-database.xml]
>   ERROR TestLnkConnection - Exception Received here!!!
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   IOException parsing XML document from file [M:\My
>   Documents\workspace-sts-3.7.0.RELEASE\LDODashBoard\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\mvc-database.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: M:\My
>   Documents\workspace-sts-3.7.0.RELEASE\LDODashBoard\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\mvc-database.xml
>   (The system cannot find the path specified)   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:343)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:251)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
>     at
>   com.implementation.TestLnkConnection.testConnection(TestLnkConnection.java:47)
>     at
>   com.implementation.TestLnkConnection.main(TestLnkConnection.java:73)
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: M:\My
>   Documents\workspace-sts-3.7.0.RELEASE\LDODashBoard\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\mvc-database.xml
>   (The system cannot find the path specified)   at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)   at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:146)  at
>   org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource.getInputStream(FileSystemResource.java:114)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
>     ... 14 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the log your problem is the FileNotFoundException.

**java.io.FileNotFoundException: M:\My Documents\workspace-sts-3.7.0.RELEASE\LDODashBoard\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\mvc-database.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)**

You need to ensure you are properly referencing the file in your web application as well as making sure its is in the correct location.

Comment: agreed but that is problem here, i can able to open the file with the path specified with out any issue,

Comment: figured out the issue it seems the directory is not getting resolved, copied the file xml file elsewhere it resolved                                                              ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("M:\\mvc-database.xml");

Comment: Glad it helped. File paths can be very fickle so its important you have a standardised approach. Remember also if you running web application from system where you don't have Admin/Super User access it may throw errors when you use it (no access allowed and that sort of rubbish). So ensure your folders/files have proper rights for applications to access without issues.